# Converting ListItems to Decimal & adding them together for a sum

Tags: c#, xamarin

What Im trying to achieve is a Budget Calculator. I have am using SQLite so all my database work needed to be in string format. below is my Save routine to show you guys...

```
void AddToBudget_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Budget Budget = new Budget()
            {
                OutgoingProductName = OProductName.Text,
                OutgoingMonthlyCostS = OMonthlyCost.Text

            };
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Budget>();
                int rowsAdded = conn.Insert(Budget);
            }
            DisplayAlert("Added!", "Your Monthly Item has been Added to Budget!", "OK");
            BindingContext = new Budget();
            OnAppearing();
        }
```

I want all `OutgoingMonthlyCostS` items to add up before I subtract on an entry box in which the user would enter their Monthly Salary in to. Below is the code for my `OutgoingMonthlyCost` & `OutgoingMonthlyCostS`...

```
private decimal outgoingMonthlyCost { get; set; }
        public decimal OutgoingMonthlyCost
        {
            get => outgoingMonthlyCost;
            set
            {
                outgoingMonthlyCost = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OutgoingMonthlyCost");
            }
        }

        private string outgoingMonthlyCostS { get; set; }
        public string OutgoingMonthlyCostS
        {
            get => outgoingMonthlyCostS;
            set
            {
                outgoingMonthlyCostS = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OutgoingMonthlyCostS");  
            }
        }

        public void outgoingMonthlyCostFin()
        {
            outgoingMonthlyCostS = outgoingMonthlyCost.ToString();
            TotalBudget();
        }
```

This is currently how I have it laid out but something isnt right as my app keeps crashing...

```
private decimal totalMonthlyCost { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalMonthlyCost
        {
            get => totalMonthlyCost;
            set
            {
                totalMonthlyCost = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("totalMonthlyCost");
                TotalBudget();
            }
        }


        private string totalMonthlyCostFin { get; set; }
        public string TotalMonthlyCostFin
        {
            get => totalMonthlyCostFin;
            set
            {
                totalMonthlyCostFin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("totalMonthlyCostFin");
            }
        }

        public void TotalBudget()
        {

            var Conversion = default(decimal);

            if (OutgoingMonthlyCost != 0)
            {
                Conversion += decimal.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(OutgoingMonthlyCostS)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                TotalMonthlyCostFin = "£" + (TotalMonthlyCost - Conversion).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                TotalMonthlyCostFin = "£0";
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Jason It wasn’t letting save to anything other than .Text thats why it needed to be a string

Comment: You are doing something wrong.  You need to figure this out and fix it before you do anything else.

Comment: @Jason I believe I can't save an entry as a real it has to be .Text  The way my app works users need to insert a value which then goes in to a listbox

Comment: Just because an Entry returns a string does not mean that you have to store it in your DB that way.  If you insist on doing it this way it is going to cause continuous problems for you at every step of development.

Comment: @Jason I have added my save routine. can you tell me where I am going wrong with it? When I change OutgoingMonthlyCostS which is the string value to OutgoingMonthlyCost which is the decimal value I get an undeline saying 'Entry does not contain a definition for Real

Comment: @BlairGibson Look at the line ```if (OutgoingMonthlyCost != 0)```--I don't see where the string OutgoingMonthlyCost gets converted to an int or double for this comparison.